# Android Icon Generator for Photo Stack

Tags: android, maps

Im looking for a library that is able to produce an icon with the following design.

It will be used like the icon generator of the google maps utils library.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.java

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with creat custom view that looks like that? will that be a good solution?

Comment: I don't really know where to statt6and how to generate the "icon" format... do you have an example?

Comment: I will write an example of a view that looks like this - image and icon to the right top. See you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can create your custom view like this:

**First, make your custom layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[13]" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ff56"
    android:text="64"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

**And here is the background drawable for your icon in the top right corner:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
    android:angle="-90"
    android:centerColor="#F2F2F2"
    android:endColor="#ADA996"
    android:startColor="#DBDBDB" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Don't forget to change the image size according to how you want your layout to look.

Comment: Nice, would be cool to have a free to use layout file with the exact design I need...

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting article here: https://medium.com/@tonyshkurenko/work-with-clustermanager-bdf3d70fb0fd